# In jupyter notebook, I commented my variable, however instead of a 'variable is not defined error' I still get value output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In a jupyter notebook, what is the reason when I commented a variable declaration and trying to call it, instead of getting a 'variable is not defined error' , I get the output before I commented that variable?

```py
import random

number = random.randint(1,9)
##user_guess = 3

def first():
    print(number)

def second():
    print(user_guess)

second()
```

Output: 3

it should be 'variable is not defined'

Comment: I see that you are new contributor. Please format your question according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks .

Comment: Are you running the code from the top in Jupyter or running only the second() function? You will to rerun from the top if you made edits

Comment: Try to restsart your kernel or jupyer to clean the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have run that cell in the notebook with the variable defined *before* you commented it out and ran the cell again. Jupyter Notebook keeps previously defined variables in memory. To get *NameError* ("user_guess not defined"), you need to restart the notebook kernel and run the cell again.

Answer (score 0):

The Jupyter runtime stores all variables in memory. For example if in one code cell you were to type

```py
x = 1
```

the variable x would be accessible in all cells you run after that as it has been stored in the computer's memory. So in the next cell if you were to type

```py
print(x)
```

`x` from the previous cell would be accessible here.

The same sort of thing is happening here – you have declared x as a variable so it is currently a variable sitting in your computer's memory. When you rerun the cell with the variable name commented out, the variable is already in your computer's memory and Jupyter does not 'undo' the result of a code cell if you rerun it so `x` is not undefined.